# shared mail address with postfix and dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot, openldap

I'm trying to set up some shared mailboxes like contact or support.

I have made it possible for me to share an IMAP folder between users in Dovecot by doing this in 15-mailboxes.conf

```
namespace {
  type = shared
  separator = /
  prefix = Shared/
  location = mbox:/mail/shared
  subscriptions = no
  list = children
  mailbox support {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox contact {
    auto = subscribe
  }
}
```

and then I'm using ACL to control who has access to each folder.

I want to make the support and contact mail addresses public, so you can email them.
But postfix keeps saying the users don't exist. I have made a file called /etc/postfix/virtualmaps and postmap it.

```
support@domain.extension support
contact@domain.extension contact
```

And in my postfix main.cf, I have added this:

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /mail/shared
virtual_mailbox_maps = lmdb:/etc/postfix/virtualmaps
```

if I add virtual_mailbox_domains = $mydomain, postfix throws errors and says that mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains cant be the same.

All users are ldap users

### Edit 1

@NikitaKipriyanov has pointed me in the direction of [`local_recipient_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps) and then I have found local_delivery that passes everything to dovecot.

It does still not work and but now its that dovecot can't find the ldap user

### Edit 2

Docecot has building feature to share an IMAP inbox: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/shared_mailboxes/#shared-mailboxes

here are som logs with local_recipient_maps active:

```
2023-07-17T14:18:21.117842+02:00 tst postfix/pickup[5200]: 1CA20213BC0: uid=0 from=<testmail@domain.test>
2023-07-17T14:18:21.127591+02:00 tst postfix/cleanup[5212]: 1CA20213BC0: message-id=<64b5318d.5XutEBb44MdWM3yJ%testmail@domain.test>
2023-07-17T14:18:21.167058+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[5199]: 1CA20213BC0: from=<testmail@domain.test>, size=449, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2023-07-17T14:18:21.230250+02:00 tst postfix/local[5214]: 1CA20213BC0: to=<support@domain.test>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.06/0.03/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "support")
2023-07-17T14:18:21.231069+02:00 tst postfix/cleanup[5212]: 38487213BC2: message-id=<20230717121821.38487213BC2@tst.nru.test>
2023-07-17T14:18:21.233902+02:00 tst postfix/bounce[5215]: 1CA20213BC0: sender non-delivery notification: 38487213BC2
2023-07-17T14:18:21.233966+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[5199]: 38487213BC2: from=<>, size=2226, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2023-07-17T14:18:21.234323+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[5199]: 1CA20213BC0: removed
2023-07-17T14:18:21.235893+02:00 tst postfix/local[5214]: 38487213BC2: to=<testmail@domain.test>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

And here are some logs with local_recipient_maps and local_delivery active:

```
2023-07-20T13:09:48.958737+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[31655]: 274CA215D35: from=<testmail@domain.test>, size=449, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2023-07-20T13:09:48.993036+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules
2023-07-20T13:09:48.993428+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules/lib01_acl_plugin.so
2023-07-20T13:09:48.993549+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(support@domain.test): Started userdb lookup
2023-07-20T13:09:48.993643+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb: Connecting
2023-07-20T13:09:48.993756+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb (pid=26599,uid=0): Client connected (fd=8)
2023-07-20T13:09:48.996561+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(support@domain.test): auth USER input:
2023-07-20T13:09:48.996672+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(support@domain.test)<31682><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(support@domain.test): Userdb lookup failed
2023-07-20T13:09:48.996765+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(31682): Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb (pid=26599,uid=0): Disconnected: Connection closed (fd=8)
2023-07-20T13:09:49.003457+02:00 tst postfix/pipe[31681]: 274CA215D35: to=<support@domain.test>, relay=dovecot, delay=903, delays=903/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown. Command output: lda(support@domain.test): Error: net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot//stats-writer) failed: Permission denied )
2023-07-20T13:09:49.009715+02:00 tst postfix/cleanup[31684]: 0233E215EBD: message-id=<20230720110949.0233E215EBD@tst.nru.test>
2023-07-20T13:09:49.012518+02:00 tst postfix/bounce[31683]: 274CA215D35: sender non-delivery notification: 0233E215EBD
2023-07-20T13:09:49.012577+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[31655]: 0233E215EBD: from=<>, size=2430, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2023-07-20T13:09:49.012611+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[31655]: 274CA215D35: removed
2023-07-20T13:09:49.022166+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules
2023-07-20T13:09:49.022500+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules/lib01_acl_plugin.so
2023-07-20T13:09:49.022610+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(testmail@domain.test): Started userdb lookup
2023-07-20T13:09:49.022700+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb: Connecting
2023-07-20T13:09:49.022821+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb (pid=26599,uid=0): Client connected (fd=8)
2023-07-20T13:09:49.025074+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(testmail@domain.test): auth USER input:
2023-07-20T13:09:49.025181+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(testmail@domain.test)<31685><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(testmail@domain.test): Userdb lookup failed
2023-07-20T13:09:49.025271+02:00 tst dovecot: lda(31685): Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot//auth-userdb (pid=26599,uid=0): Disconnected: Connection closed (fd=8)
2023-07-20T13:09:49.027037+02:00 tst postfix/pipe[31681]: 0233E215EBD: to=<testmail@domain.test>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown. Command output: lda(testmail@domain.test): Error: net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot//stats-writer) failed: Permission denied )
2023-07-20T13:09:49.027394+02:00 tst postfix/qmgr[31655]: 0233E215EBD: removed
```

Comment: All virtual_* settings are for virtual domains; that is, when a single Postfix instance is serving more than one mail domain, for example both "example.com" and "example.org" at the same time. If you don't have that, use mailbox_maps, your mailbox should appear there. Then, you need to make sure dovecot won't reject it but deliver into desired shared mailbox.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I knew that virtual_mailbox_domains was to server multiple domains, but didn't know that it was possible to remove the virtual in the other settings. 

I have tried it:
`mailbox_base = /mail/shared` `mailbox_maps = lmdb:/etc/postfix/virtualmaps`

but now postfix says  that the settings are unused?

Comment: I was mistaken, the mailbox maps setting for domains in `mydestination` is called [`local_recipient_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps). This is where you add your additional addresses for Postfix to not reject mails to these addresses. Note that you can have *more than one* map assigned to *_maps setting and their results will be combined. Again, make sure Dovecot won't reject them too but deliver to proper mailbox.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
It still bounces with unknown user error. I have tried to play a little with local delivery, because it seems like dovecot never sees the mail before the bounce. But that didn't work either, maybe just because I'm setting it up wrong?

Comment: If I knew a full answer I'd suggest it in the "answer" box. I never worked with Dovecot. Cyrus IMAP has a special syntax which allows you to post mail into shared mailbox or directly into non-INBOX of ordinary users with standard LMTP delivery agent; in that case, the mail address looks like "prefix+mailbox" where prefix is user name or, for shared mailboxes, is configured; also you need to add "post" permission on that mailbox to anyone. And, to route nice address like "support@domain" into such address, you set up an alias in Postfix. Maybe, Dovecot has similar mechanism?

Comment: And, show logs! At least, Postfix logs, from which I will be able to say is that a problem on Postfix or Dovecot side.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov You are correct that logs are need, im sorry they weren't there at the time. Dovecot does have a buildin feature to share IMAP inboxes, with is working just fine. I have linked to how that is working. I have just made a shared namespace as shown in the post and then using ACL to control who has access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

If I just use postfix alias feature, I can make postfix deliver it directly to the mailbox and not lookup if the "user" exist

So the way I did it was to update my alias file and added:

```
support /mail/shared/support
contact /mail/shared/contact
```

I will have to test if this means that I have bypassed spamassasin and the virus scanner. I will update this answer when I know that